# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' error I've tried everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

## Asking for total price, tax and tip. Then adding each other and giving the total price.

```
from time import sleep 
def getprice():
    return input("What's the price of your bill?").lower()

price = getprice()

def gettax():
    return input("What's the restaurant's tax percent?").lower()

tax = gettax()

def gettip():
    return input("How much tip do you want to leave?")

tip = gettip()

percentage = float(tax)/100
total= price*percentage + price + tip

print(total)
```

It's giving me and error on the total= row, I read many articles but I can't fix it can anyone help me ?

Comment: ya, you need to convert corrs variables to ints or floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns a string.

You have tried  `float * string + string + string`

```
total= price*percentage + price + tip

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

You can fix like this,

```
from time import sleep 
def getprice():
    return float(input("What's the price of your bill?").lower())

price = getprice()

def gettax():
    return float(input("What's the restaurant's tax percent?").lower())

tax = gettax()

def gettip():
    return float(input("How much tip do you want to leave?"))

tip = gettip()

percentage = tax / 100
total= price*percentage + price + tip

print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've finally understood my mistake. I was very dumb, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The input read is a string, that is a sequence, not multipliable by a float.

```
int(price)
```

Solves it.